# How to Specify Minimum Percentage Height with Wrap Content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have a ConstraintLayout with some views in it. I want it to have a minimum height of some percentage of its parent. But it should also be allowed to grow larger if necessary depending on its content.

Doesn't seem like there's a way to specify minimum heights as a percentage though.

Comment: you can use `android:minHeight=""` property

Comment: That does not allow you set percentage values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get your parent height programmatically
and set `minimumHeight` to your view (you can change 0.8 to any percent you want)

```
parentLayout.post {

    yourView.minimumHeight = (parentLayout.height * 0.8).toInt()
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

**Try this method by passing percentage ratio of height/width**

```
fun getDeviceWidthInPercentage(percentage: Int): Int {
    val displayMetrics = 
    MyApplication.getAppInstance()?.resources?.displayMetrics
    return if (displayMetrics != null) {
        val toMultiply = percentage / 100f
        val pixels = displayMetrics.widthPixels * toMultiply
        pixels.toInt()
    } 
}
```

How to call:

```
YOUR_LAYOUT.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    Helper.getDeviceWidthInPercentage(100),
    Helper.getDeviceHeightInPercentage(85)
    )
```